# glog-0.3.5 getting logging.h not found in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode10.1

When I tried to run the app from Xcode(10.1) then getting the following error.

```
logging.h not found.
```

It's working fine while running an app in Android.

```
  react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
  react-native: 0.59.8 => 0.59.8 
  Node: 8.11.4
  Yarn: 1.16.0
  Xcode: 10.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['glog/logging.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657043/glog-logging-h-file-not-found)

Comment: @hardworker No, there is no file with this name.

Comment: @hardworker It is working with version 0.58.6 version, and facing the same error with 0.59.x version.